# ¿Cómo hacer para que en pseint el comando "Repetir" "Hasta que" acepte más de una expresión y no salte el error "Se esperaba solo una expresión?

Tags: pseint

¿Cómo hacer para que en pseint el comando "Repetir" "Hasta que" acepte más de una expresión y no salte el error "Se esperaba solo una  expresión?

Answer (score 0):

Muy buenas,

Diría que en pseint, al ser un lenguaje de aprendizaje está muy capado, y solo se puede tener una expresión en los bucles "repetir-hasta que".

Supongo que la única manera de hacerlo sería poniendo un bloque "si" dentro del bucle, aunque en cualquier otro lenguaje sería una solución muy poco elegante.

Un saludo